# Access to the files beyond Wine's virtual disks

Tags: files, wine

I would like to know if the executables run through Wine have any access beyond the virtual drives provided by Wine (e.g. `C:/`, `D:/`)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a `z:` drive which is the Linux file system.  Also you can define drives that point to any folder for which you have access.

If you want to confine programs running in Wine to parts of the filesystem, remove the `z:` drive and declare drives just for the parts that you want to make accessible. You can do this from the “Configure Wine” entry in the Wine menu or by modifying the symbolic links in `~/.wine/dosdevices/`.

Comment: is there any way to limit Wine and programs run thru it to the ~/.wine and below?

Comment: You would have to remove the z: drive on the drives tab and redefine all the folders on the desktop integration tab.

Comment: Choose "configure wine" from the wine menu

Comment: thanks for help, if there is only C:/ listed, then that means program ran by Wine can't access anything below ~/.wine?

Comment: yes c: is located in ~/.wine/dosdevices/c: so unless one or more of the desktop integration folders is pointing outside of c: then the software would be limited to ~/.wine/dosdevices/c: and below.

Comment: Wine is not a sandbox – a program can use Linux syscalls to interact with the rest of the system bypassing Wine, although this is unlikely to happen unless the program was intentionally written to do that.